# Webserver needed for django WSGI API?

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, django, uwsgi

My app is just a REST API written in django. There is no static content or html pages served. In setting up our production environment, we are planning on using amazon ELB (load balancer) to balance requests between many EC2 instances running django and uWSGI.

With this setup, do we need (or want) to use a webserver like nginx to handle accepting http requests and passing them to uWSGUI? What benefits (if any) would this provide us over just running uWSGI on the webserver and having it accept http requests straight from the loadbalancer?

Thanks!